# SQLAlchemy Mapper Events don't get triggered

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

**I can't get [Mapper Events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/events.html#mapper-events) to trigger in SqlAlchemy 2.0**

**tl;dr:** I am able to perform operations but events never trigger.

Below is the example they have in their [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/events.html#mapper-events):

```py
def my_before_insert_listener(mapper, connection, target):
    # execute a stored procedure upon INSERT,
    # apply the value to the row to be inserted
    target.calculated_value = connection.execute(
        text("select my_special_function(%d)" % target.special_number)
    ).scalar()

# associate the listener function with SomeClass,
# to execute during the "before_insert" hook
event.listen(
    SomeClass, 'before_insert', my_before_insert_listener)
```

And here, is my attempt to implement basically the same thing:

```py
# models.py

from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, DateTime, func, event, MetaData

metadata_obj = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata_obj)

class Opportunity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "opportunity"
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True, default=generate)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

opportunity_table = Opportunity.__table__
```

I also have the following listener

```py
#models.py 

def opportunity_after_update(mapper, connection, target):
    print(f"Opportunity {target.id} was updated!")
event.listen(Opportunity, 'after_update', opportunity_after_update)
```

The following code successfully updates the table in my database, but the listener never gets called:

```py
with Session() as session:
    session.query(Opportunity).filter_by(id=some_id).update({'name'='New Name'})
    session.commit()
```

Any clues that may be helpful?

Comment: I'm not sure where this is documented in the 2.0 docs, but this form of updates doesn't work with most events, you need to use the  do_orm_execute event (see the second warning block [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#selecting-a-synchronization-strategy)).

Comment: I'm so confused! So what's the best-practice way to do pre and post update hooks?

Comment: For clarity: you are intentionally using `session.query(Opportunity).update({'name': 'new_value'})` because you want to update rows that are not in the session, is that right?  As opposed to doing `some_opportunity.name = 'new_value'` on an instance of `Opportunity` that is already in the session?

Comment: Sorry, if not using the query, how can I load/modify an existing row? I may have been using an anti-pattern all this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to modify an existing record, there are (at least) two approaches that you could take.

Firstly, you could retrieve the record an modify it in the session.

```py
with Session() as s:
    opportunity = s.get(Opportunity, some_id)
    opportunity.name = 'new_name'
    s.commit()
```

In this case, because the object involved is guaranteed to be in the session,  mapper event listeners will pick up any changes and report them (or perform some other action that you define).

Secondly, you can use the "update with custom where clause method":

```py
with Session() as s:
    s.query(Opportunity).filter_by(id=some_id).update({'name': 'new_name'})
    s.commit()
```

In this case, the session will [not necessarily contain references to the updated rows](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/dml.html#selecting-a-synchronization-strategy), so mapper event listeners will not be notified of them.

The recommended solution for capturing such events is to use a [do_orm_execute](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.SessionEvents.do_orm_execute) listener.  Such a listener will intercept:

> all top-level SQL statements invoked from the Session.execute() method, as well as related methods such as Session.scalars() and Session.scalar()

*(quotation taken from the previous link; `session.query` and `session.execute` can be considered to be equivalent here)*

Which update method you choose - and consequently which listeners you can use - depends on your use case.  The first method is most common, but the second method is useful if you want to update an arbitrarily large collection of rows, for example "all the rows in the users table whose name column is equal to 'John'".

Comment: This does the trick. 
The opportunity table gets updated and my events are getting triggered. 

With that being said, even though everything SEEMS to work, I'm getting the following error: Instance <Opportunity at 0x292f1d9d840> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed. 

Any idea why?

Comment: Not sure why - using `session.get()` ought to guarantee that the object is in the session.  Could you post a new question with a [mre] for this case?

Comment: My guess is that it's because after I commit (thus ending the transaction), I THEN pass the opportunity back (I'm just using it to return values, not to write), but I guess it's complaining it can't refresh them.

As in:

...
session.commit()
return opportunity

Comment: You could try passing `expire_on_commit=False` to your session constructor.